# ReactJS facing issue regarding clearing checkboxes checked state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a issue in trying to find and figure out a way to clear those checkboxes that are checked back into its original state(unchecked). I have a button known as "Clear Filter" that link to the const handleclear, It will allows me to perform two things:

1)To reset the filteredList data and return to its default value displayed(which i had already done)

2)To turn all the current checked checkboxes into unchecked( i tried different way from different reference that i can find but i failed to achieve)

So may i know if there's a way to clear the checkboxes checked state using the button? As i am running out of idea to troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Controlled Components

If you want React to manage the state of your inputs you want to use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). With this pattern, React becomes the 'single source of truth' for the state of the input.

A simple controlled checkbox would look like this:

```
function ControlledCheckbox() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  
  function handleChange() {
    setChecked(!checked)
  }

  return <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

### Using checkboxes with filtering

In the current case where you are filtering data using checkboxes, the `checked` attribute can be set as a boolean which is true/false depending on whether the particular filter criterion represented by that checkbox is included in the user's chosen filter criteria.

```
const criteriaChoices = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

function App() {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = React.useState(['foo']); 

  const handleChange(e) {
    const checkboxId = e.target.id
    setCriteria(criteria.includes(checkboxId)
      ? criteria.filter(c => c !== checkboxId)
      : [...criteria, checkboxId]
    )
  };

  return criteriaChoices.map(choice => (
    <label key={choice} for={choice}>
      <input 
        id={choice} 
        type="checkbox"
        checked={criteria.includes(choice)} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
      />
      {choice}
    </label>
  ))
```

In the above, the first checkbox rendered will be ticked because the `criteria` in state includes `'foo'`. The other two will be unticked to start with because `'bar'` and `'baz'` are not in the `criteria` in state.

The `handleChange` function adds/removes the clicked filter criterion depending on whether or not it is already in `criteria`. Note you don't need to check `e.target.checked` because React is in full control of the state on which the checkbox's `checked` attribute depends.

### Resetting

Once your components are controlled, you can reset the checkboxes easily by resetting the state on which the `checked` attribute depends. So in the above code, calling `setCriteria([])` in a `handleReset` function would mean that `criteria.includes(choice)` is always `false` and therefore every checkbox would remain unchecked.

#### With Material-UI

I took the liberty of distilling the essential elements of the issue from your code and put together [a small example using Mui components on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lamarr-gserz?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I tested it out, the clear checkboxes work but the filtering work in a different direction. Regardless i'll use the example that you shown to me as a guideline for my code